# Parsing a string which I am not able to identify as Object or Array or Json

Tags: php, arrays, parsing, object

I am receiving an array in response of a request. And when I do print_r on it, this is what I am getting `Array( [receiver] => {:email=>"email@domain.com"})`.

I am not able to understand how can I access value of ":email".

Please help.

**EDIT:**

Here is the var_dump of the response.

```
array ( 'receiver' => '{:email=>"email@domain.com"}' )
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the output of `var_dump($yourarray)`?

Comment: See comments by @Pateman on Mike B's answer. What you have is the string `{:email=>"email@domain.com"}`, so you'll have to parse it on your own.

Comment: I deleted my answer since I was way-off on my assumption of your data-structure. best of luck!

Comment: @bfavaretto Sorry for late reply. I have edited question with var_dump of response. is there any other way than using regex on it?

Comment: @Vivek - what's wrong about using a regex here?

Comment: @Pateman - Nothing is wrong with it. But as I need to do it for many other places, and I was hoping that it might be some sort of structure like object or something so just wanted to explore any possibilities. Anyway Thanks.

Comment: Well, you can build a basic parser of such a string using `trim()` and `explode()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use regular expression to get the email.

```
$arr = array('recebodor' => '{:email=>"someone@example.com"}');

$email = preg_replace('/{:email=>"([^"]+)"}/', '$1', $arr['recebodor']);
echo $email; // someone@example.com
```

**Explanation:**

```
{:email=>    Match with the "{:email=>" in the string
"([^"]+)"    Get any character within double quotes
}            Match with the last "}"
$1           Replace all text with the text found inside parentheses
```

Comment: ok. Thanks. But isn't ":email" should be part of some data structure? and we should be able to access it by traversing or something?

Comment: @bsdnoobz I edited the email address on your answer. This kind of thing is considered spam here on StackOverflow.

Comment: @bfavaretto I don't know about that. Thanks!